# How to use Regex in kusto query

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer, kql

So I have a Kusto query like this

```
exceptions
| extend A_= tostring(customDimensions.A)
| where A_ in~ ("Could not get notes: From:", "failed to call", "Custom conference list" )
// | where A_ contains 'Could not get notes: From:' //This is working when I use "contains" operator but fails to check below 2 items when the first item doesn't exist
// | where A_ contains 'Custom conference list'
// | where A_ contains 'failed to call'
```

The first item in the list is "Could not get notes: From:", where it has multiple ID at the end of the string

For example;

Could not get notes: From: abcd

Could not get notes: From: abcdef

What I am trying to do is take all the items that start with "Could not get notes: From:" and use them in the "in~" operator.

So far I have tried using contains operator like below

```
|where A_ contains 'Could not get notes: From:' // This seems to be working as it will outputting every item that starts with "Could not get notes: From:" but when I am trying to use it in the "in~" it is failing.
```

The problem with using the "contains" operator for each unique item is if any of the items(let's say for 3 items) will not there, the query returns no results even if 2 items still exist.

Not sure if this has a better solution to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `has_any` instead:

```
exceptions
| extend A_= tostring(customDimensions.A)
| where A_ has_any ("Could not get notes: From:", "failed to call", "Custom conference list")
```

Also, note that `contains` is significantly slower than `has`/`has_any`, because the latter uses the index to only fetch relevant records, while `contains` scans all the records. Note, however, that there's a semantic difference between the two: `contains` looks for substrings, while `has` only looks for full tokens. For example, `"hello world" contains "hell"` will return `true`, while `"hello world" has "hell"` will return `false`. See more info in the [String Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/datatypes-string-operators) doc.

Comment: Just found the solution. But I wasn't aware of which one is better when it comes to speed. Thank you very much for the further explanation @Slavik N